# Aside element on the SIDE - html question

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and im just trying out some stuff.  I tried to use the aside element to have a little box on the right side of the screen but could not get it right, eventually I used margins to move it to the right spot but there would be a big empty space on the left side and it would all look messed up on displays with very low or very large displays and screen resolutions.

```css
html {
        border-style: double;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 12px;
        margin-top: 24px;
        margin-right: 24px;
        margin-left: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
    aside {
        border-style: double;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 12px;
        object-position: right;
        margin-left: 1000px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    h2 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    p {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Software Boi</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Website <strong>title</strong></h1>
        <h2>Aside element test</h2>
        <article>
        <aside>
            <h2><strong>How Do I...</strong></h2>
            <p>*Have a box on the right side like this</p>
            <p>*But without the gap/break next to it</p>
        </aside>
        <h3>E.g this should be to the left the box not underneath it</h3>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://github.com/tootloose'">buttons are cool</button>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: user **float right** or use Grid System from Bootstrap

Comment: Windows key + shift + S let's you take better snippets so you don't have to scratch out details in screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
aside {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  object-position: right;
  float: right;
}
```

Instead of:

```
aside {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  object-position: right;
  margin-left: 1000px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```